# How can I automatically sync data in my PC folder with my android phone?

Tags: android, sync, cloud

Suggest the best apps that can help me automatically sync between a folder in my Ubuntu PC and my Android phone.

Comment: bittorrent sync snycs your devices on a p2p basis. No central servers, no additional service needed, just an internet connection.

Comment: Will try that. Let us see if any more suggestions arrive. Based on http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/02/howto-install-bittorrent-sync-from-its-official-repository/ - it seems that syncs need to be manual.

Comment: I also used Dropbox (on desktop) with Autosync Dropbox - Dropsync (Android) a while ago and was pretty happy. Dropsync only syncs specified directories in your dropbox to your Android. Convenient, but it is Dropbox: You share your files with a company. If you are ok with that, this is a reliable and easy to manage solution.

Comment: KDE Connect. Google "kde connect sync files to phone" or see this page [Using KDE Connect to Sync your Android Device with Your Linux Computer](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/kde-connect-sync-android-linux/)